# Returning Data from ASP.NET Core 6 Web API controller slow performance

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

We've have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project C#, which we originally upgraded from ASP.NET Core 3.1. We are currently having an issue where any APIs with

```
return new JsonResult(data)
```

It is incredibly slow (32 seconds for 120k rows), yet doing a

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
```

takes only about 3 seconds.

The issue is after the return statement, as

```
var testResult = new JsonResult(data);
return restResult; //Slow after this. Issue here.
```

gets to the return line quickly, but then something after the return adds 30 seconds. A brief investigation suggests something within .NET 6 has changed in regards to buffers and writing to disk, but I don't want to lead you down a potentially wrong rabbit hole.

We use Newtonsoft Json (6.0.20) but the issue also happens with `System.Text.Json` (6.0.8).

**UPDATE:** doing a simple switch to .NET 7 resolves the issue but .NET 7 is not a long-term support version.

The code below downloads all the 'edges' data from Neo4j, which itself takes about 6 seconds. 6 seconds and neo4j is fine. Everything works nicely until it gets to the 'return ...' part, and it impacts every Json return on every API so it seems to be site-wide.

I believe it's only happened since moving to .NET 6.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns all edges and required information from the Neo4j database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An array of edges with GeoJson.</returns>
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("AllNetwork")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllMap()
    {
        //checks latest version is in cache.
        int version = neo.GetLatestNetworkStatusVersion();

        if (neo.GetNetworkStatus(version) < NetworkStatus.Uploaded)
        {
            return new JsonResult(CachedNetworkResult.NETWORK_MAINTENANCE());
        }
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        if (mainMapCache == null || !mainMapCache.Valid(version))
        {
            mainMapCache = null;
            GC.Collect();

            //download new cache if newer is available or no cache loaded
            mainMapCache = new APINetworkResultCache(version)
            {
                Result = await neo.GetMapAllAsync() //Array []
            };
        }
        else
        {
            mainMapCache.CacheUsed = true;
        }

        var res = CachedNetworkResult.SUCCESS(mainMapCache);
        mainMapCache.DownloadTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Retrieved network in {mainMapCache.DownloadTime:N0}ms");

        return Json(res); //ISSUE HERE
    }
```

I have tried:

- `return new JsonResult(res);`
- Setting 'OutputFormatterMemoryBufferThreshold' to 30MB and 300MB from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40579 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcnewtonsoftjsonoptions.outputformattermemorybufferthreshold?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcnewtonsoftjsonoptions-outputformattermemorybufferthreshold
- Remove async/await and making it synchronous.
- MvcOptions.SuppressOutputFormatterBuffering = true
- Both options from https://purple.telstra.com/blog/how-we-sped-up-an-aspnet-core-endpoint-from-20-seconds-down-to-4-seconds
- Retrieving the result via Postman (same time). 23.7MB file
- Not using Newtonsoft Json and used default.
  .NET 7 works perfectly and returns data within 1 second (with no other modifications).
- Return new JsonResult, return Json, return Ok, return Content.

This is part of our `startup.cs` file that references Newtonsoft JSON:

```
services.AddMvc()
    //.AddJsonOptions(options =>
    //{
    //    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    //    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
    //})
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();

// Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: You could perhaps try yield the results already: `Result = (await neo.GetMapAllAsync()).ToList()`. Another thought is if the data is coming from a database, add an index on the fields you're filtering on

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The issue is not in the database calling part, it's on the return of the action. The GetMapAllAsync returns an array.

Comment: Are you calling the endpoint from swagger ui? If so, try doing the call using postman

Comment: [(Just adding as a possible reference)](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21245)

Comment: [This article](https://purple.telstra.com/blog/how-we-sped-up-an-aspnet-core-endpoint-from-20-seconds-down-to-4-seconds) seems to point in the same direction - Large responses first being buffered to the filesystem before being streamed to the client... Maybe you can try setting the `MvcOptions.SuppressOutputFormatterBuffering` to `true` and see if that helps anything

Comment: Out of `return new JsonResult(data)`, I am guessing it is the `new JsonResult(data)` part that is slow? Once created (that is after a long wait), `return`-ing it is fast?

Comment: Thanks all. I've tried all of the items above but to no avail. @taylorswiftfan, it is at the return part. If I do var test = new JsonResult(data); return data; the test part is near instant. Something seems to be happening after the return.

Comment: It works beautifully in .NET 7. Returns result within 1-7s depending on if network is cached or not.

Comment: Ok. This really indicates a problem with the `OutputFormatters` or later. EDIT Wait so if you use System.Text.Json it runs faster?

Comment: If I just do a simple switch to .NET 7 in the project settings, it's all sorted so something is with .NET 6. I have tried System.Text.Json and it's the same issue. Thanks again, appreciated!

Answer (score -3):

Your question doesn't have enough details to advise something else. But if you are happy with

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
```

you can try

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
return Content(json, "application/json");
```

if it doesn't work, then your problem is not in serialization, it is on the way between a server and a client.

Comment: This did not work, sorry.

Comment: @Liam But now you know that serialization has nothing to do. Delay is in another place. This was the goal of my answer. Fix your question  by puting a link to my answer.